# Mac上でflaskを使用しようとしたのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: python3, macos, flask

Mac上でflaskを使用したら、警告が出てきてしまい解決案を探しています。
コードは以下です。

```
$ flask run

* Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production 
  environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2019 15:29:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2019 15:29:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2019 15:29:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2019 15:29:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2019 15:29:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: 本筋とは関係ないけど error と warning の違いはしっかり把握しとくといいですよ．

Answer (score 0):

> Use a production WSGI server instead.

解決策も警告と一緒に表示されてます。
flask に組み込まれたWebサーバーは 脆弱なので production 環境で使用するには  gunicorn や uWSGI などの WSGI サーバーと組み合わせて使うのが推奨されてるのだと思います。